# How to maintain the table relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am creating a pojo class in spring mvc. I am trying to have a product class which will have n number of products and each of which can follow under different categories.

As the categories of these products will remain the same. Let say it will have only 5 different categories by default.

Now I have to relate the each product to related categories.

Question:

I the above case how can I relate the product to different categories?

Which relationship will be suitable in hibernate.(One to many or many to one)?

How this relationship can be designed?

Comment: If a Product can have many Categories, and a Category can have many Products, this is known as `many-to-many`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement I can think of 2 particular cases below:

1. If a **category** can have n number of **products** but a **product** can belong to only one particular **category** then relationship from **Category to Product** will be **1 to Many**.
2. If a **category** can have n number of **products** and also a **product** can belong to n number of **categories** then relationship between **category** to **product** will be **many to many** in which case you also need to have a third table which will be a **JOIN** table.

Comment: As I have fixed categories, how should go first with UI prespective? Should I have to add the categories available first by admin and then I have add the product

Comment: Yes you can very well have a separate UI page for adding categories (having admin level rights).Then you have a separate page for adding products to those fixed set of categories